# JavaScript Smoother Multiplication Circle

Tags: javascript, animation, multiplication, modulo

### The Idea

I came across this idea of multiplication circles from a YouTube video that I stumbled upon and I thought that would be a fun thing to try and recreate using JavasSript and the canvas element.
[The Original Video](https://youtu.be/qhbuKbxJsk8?t=740)

### The Problem

I smoothed out the animation the best I could but it still doesn't look as proper as I'd like. I suspect coming up with a solution would require a decent amount of math. To grasp the problem in detail I think it's easier to look at the code

```js
window.onload = () => {
  const app = document.querySelector('#app')
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  const { cos, sin, PI } = Math
  const Tao = PI * 2
  const width = window.innerWidth
  const height = window.innerHeight
  const cx = width / 2
  const cy = height / 2
  const baseNumberingSystem = 200
  const stop = 34
  let color = 'teal'
  let multiplier = 0
  let drawQue = []

  // setup canvas
  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height

  class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, r, strokeColor, fillColor) {
      this.x = x
      this.y = y
      this.r = r
      this.strokeColor = strokeColor || '#fff'
      this.fillColor = fillColor || '#fff'
    }

    draw(stroke, fill) {
      ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y)
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Tao)
      ctx.closePath()

      if (fill) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor
        ctx.fill()
      }

      if (stroke) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = this.strokeColor
        ctx.stroke()
      }
    }

    createChildCircleAt(degree, radius, strokeColor, fillColor) {
      const radian = degreeToRadian(degree)
      const x = this.x + (this.r * cos(radian))
      const y = this.y + (this.r * sin(radian))
      return new Circle(x, y, radius, strokeColor, fillColor)
    }

    divideCircle(nTimes, radius) {
      const degree = 360 / nTimes
      let division = 1;
      while (division <= nTimes) {
        drawQue.push(this.createChildCircleAt(division * degree, radius))
        division++
      }
    }
  }

  function degreeToRadian(degree) {
    return degree * (PI / 180)
  }

  function draw() {
    const mainCircle = new Circle(cx, cy, cy * 0.9)
    
    // empty the que
    drawQue = []
    // clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "black"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height)

    // redraw everything
    mainCircle.draw()
    mainCircle.divideCircle(baseNumberingSystem, 4)
    drawQue.forEach(item => item.draw())

    // draw modular times table
    for (let i = 1; i <= drawQue.length; i++) {
      const product = i * multiplier;
      const firstPoint = drawQue[i]
      const secondPoint = drawQue[product % drawQue.length]

      if (firstPoint && secondPoint) {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
        ctx.strokeStyle = color
        ctx.lineTo(secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y)
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()
      }
    }
  }

  function animate() {
    multiplier+= 0.1
    multiplier = parseFloat(multiplier.toFixed(2))
    draw()
  
    console.log(multiplier, stop)

    if (multiplier === stop) {
      clearInterval(animation)
    }
  }

  app.appendChild(canvas)
  let animation = setInterval(animate, 120)
}
```

So the main issue comes from when we increment the multiplier by values less than 1 in an attempt to make the animation more fluid feeling. Example: `multiplier+= 0.1`. When we do this it increase the amount of times our if block in our draw function will fail because the secondPoint will return null.

```js
      const product = i * multiplier; // this is sometimes a decimal
      const firstPoint = drawQue[i]
      const secondPoint = drawQue[product % drawQue.length] // therefore this will often not be found

      // Then this if block wont execute. Which is good because if it did we the code would crash
      // But I think what we need is an if clause to still draw a line to a value in between the two
      // closest indices of our drawQue 
      if (firstPoint && secondPoint) {
        //...
      }
```

#### Possible Solution

I think what I'd need to do is when we fail to find the secondPoint get the remainder of `product % drawQue.length` and use that to create a new circle in between the two closest circles in the drawQue array and use that new circle as the second point of our line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My possible solution ended up working. I'll leave the added else if block here for anyone whos interested. I also had to store the degree value in my circle objects when they were made as well as calculate the distance between each subdivision of the circle.

##### Added If Else Statement

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= drawQue.length; i++) {
  const product = i * multiplier;
  const newIndex = product % drawQue.length
  const firstPoint = drawQue[i]
  const secondPoint = drawQue[newIndex]

  if (firstPoint && secondPoint) {
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
    ctx.strokeStyle = color
    ctx.lineTo(secondPoint.x, secondPoint.y)
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
  } else if (!secondPoint) {
    const percent = newIndex % 1
    const closest = drawQue[Math.floor(newIndex)]
    const newDegree = closest.degree + (degreeIncriments * percent)
    const target = mainCircle.createChildCircleAt(newDegree, 4)

    if (firstPoint && target) {
      ctx.beginPath()
      ctx.moveTo(firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y)
      ctx.strokeStyle = color
      ctx.lineTo(target.x, target.y)
      ctx.closePath()
      ctx.stroke()
    }
  }
```

##### Other changes

```js
  // ...
  const degreeIncriments = 360 / baseNumberingSystem
  // ... 
  class Circle {
    constructor(/* ... */, degree )
      // ... 
      this.degree = degree || 0
  }
```

Hope someone finds this useful...

Answer (score 0):

If you use requestAnimationFrame it looks smooth

```
function animate() {
    if (multiplier != stop) {
    multiplier+= 0.1
    multiplier = parseFloat(multiplier.toFixed(2))
    draw()
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
  }

  app.appendChild(canvas)
  animate()
```

Comment: why not make the multiplier based off of the delta parameter supplied by requestAnimationFrame

Comment: try the implementation I came up with. There's probably room for optimizing but you should be able to tell that now there's a lot more detail in the animation that was missing.